# Texture painting "Missing Materials" error message

Tags: materials, texture-painting

I'm following a guide (https://youtu.be/vmOmp0rvFVY). I'm trying to paint a 3D model in Photoshop and/or Gimp using the Quick Edit tool but it's only showing the alpha checker pattern.

There are two major differences between the tutorial and what I'm seeing in Texture Paint mode, they are shown below mine being on the right which shows "Missing Materials" as apposed to "Missing Texture".
[image: tutorial on the left my blender window on the right]

Comment: Probably materials are missing on the object ? Did you add any materials to it before attempting to add a texture ?

Comment: I've added a new material to the object then I have to manually paint over it to get the image I want into Photoshop/Gimp, for some reason its importing the Lamp icon too.

Comment: The *Missing Materials* warning will be shown only if the object you're trying to paint on doesn't have any materials. In this case it will be shown white as well. If it has materials but doesn't have textures it will be shown as pink in the viewport.

Comment: I think I've resolved the issue by Quick editing in Materials mode instead of Texture mode